# add new column in birt report based on generated grand total column in crosstab

Tags: report, birt

Thanks for reading my question.
Please I need your help here.

I am trying to add a column that is based on a cross-tab's grand total. The cross-tab was added by clicking on the totals option for the column. Now I want to use this total for another calculation in my cross-tab but its so difficult adding a column after the grand total column.
Secondly its difficult getting a reference to the results in the grand total column.

Please what do you advice?

Thanks

Ime